# PHP - Am I calling a function correctly?

Tags: php, function

Here is my code:

```
$oldPhone = $_POST["phone"];

$newPhone = makeInteger($oldPhone);

lengthMustBe($newPhone, 10, "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number.");
```

Here is the function:

```
function lengthMustBe($str, $length, $errormsg) {

    if (strlen($str) != $length) {
        $status = "failure";
        $error = $errormsg;
    }

};
```

The function is pretty self explanatory..

When I try to pass it `"123", 10, "Not long enough"`, $status is still "success" (defined at top of page.)

Comment: remove ; at the end of the function + you need to define the function above all of your code

Comment: How do you check for `$status` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the `$status` variable like:

```
$tmpArray = lengthMustBe($newPhone, 10, "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number.");
$status = $tmpArray[0];
$statusMsg = $tmpArray[1];
```

and your function:

```
function lengthMustBe($str, $length, $errormsg) {

    if (strlen($str) != $length) {

        return array("failure", $errormsg);
    }
    else
    {
        return array("success", "");
    }
}
```

don't use globals its just a terrible idea...

Comment: Yeah, I get how I would receive back "failure", but I also need the error message returned back... how can I do this?

Comment: @RickBross - check the updated answer.. all you need is to return an array for the status and the message. you can change "failure" and "success" strings to boolean values like true or false.

Answer (score 2):

How is $status defined at the top of the page? My guess is the scope of $status in this function makes it a different variable then the one defined at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of `$status` var is inside the function lengthMustBe.

You can define `$status` as a global var like this :

```
function lengthMustBe($str, $length, $errormsg) {
    global $status;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think $status is not global... meaning it'll only be "failure" within that function, but when you try to call it from elsewhere, the global $status is called - which has been defined as "success" at the top of the page.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php